# How can I call the one method in all the view controllers?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

How can I call the one method in all the view controllers?

One method in viewcontroller1 like,

```
- (void)doSearch
{
   NSLog(@"Search..!");
}
```

I want to call `doSearch` method from viewcontroller2, viewcontroller3, viewcontroller4, viewcontroller5, etc.

How to do this?

Comment: You need to make clear:  Does this method refer to any instance variables of the containing class?  If not, you can use most of the below techniques.  But if instance variables are referenced you need to use a superclass or some other more involved scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare this method in `AppDelegate.h`. like

```
- (void)doSearch;
```

And Implement it in `AppDelegate.m` like

```
- (void)doSearch
{
    //Your Search Logic
}
```

Then, Create `AppDelegate` instance like

```
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Make Your Project's `.pch` file look like following:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__

    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    #import "AppDelegate.h"
    AppDelegate *appDelegate;

#endif
```

Now, From Any `ViewController`, You can call method like:

```
[appDelegate doSearch];
```

Happy Coding.

**NOTE:** Personally, I avoid this kind of implementation in `AppDelegate` Class.
I use Singleton Object Pattern for this kind of purpose. But, Given is the quickest way.

***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_EDIT_*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

Add a New Class file of `NSObject` type: Name it `CommonMethod` (or whatever you want)

in `CommonMethod.h`

```
@interface CommonMethods : NSObject
+ (CommonMethods *)sharedObject;
+ (void)doSearch;
```

in `CommonMethod.m`

```
#import "CommonMethods.h"

@implementation CommonMethods

+ (CommonMethods *)sharedObject 
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static CommonMethods *sharedObject;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^ { sharedObject = [[CommonMethods alloc] init]; });
    return sharedObject;
}

+ (BOOL)doSearch
{
    // Your Search Logic.
}
```

Now, Add `#import "CommonMethods.h"` to your project's `.pch` file.

And You are all set to go...!!!

Method Call (in any of your viewController):  `[CommonMethods doSearch];`

Comment: Thank you matt. can you give sample code for Singleton method.

Comment: @Matt : What is the need for the shared instance for just calling a method?

Comment: @LithuT.V If you see my answer thoroughly, I didn't used its shared instance for the (class)method calling. It is just, in case, if the user wants to create an instance method to be called from anywhere. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare it in separate class and instantiate that class in all viewControllers, or you could define this method in your `AppDelegate` and call in all your viewController. you could access the AppDelegate in your ViewControllers by getting its instance like this

```
self.appDelegate=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

and finally call the method like this

```
[self.appDelegate doSearch];
```

Generally it is preferable to declare all your methods or data which is shared through the application in a separate class and use this class. I usually use `singelton` Object class in my application, define all the shared data in that and finally access in all classes

here is example of singelton class

MyData.h

```
@interface MyData : NSObject

+(MyData*)getInstance;
-(void)search;

@end
```

MyData.m

```
#import "MyData.h"

@implementation MyData



static MyData *instance =nil;

+(MyData *)getInstance
{

    @synchronized(self)
    {
    if(instance==nil)
        {

        instance= [[MyData alloc]init];
        }
    }
    return instance;
}

-(void)search {
    NSLog(@"search");
}

@end
```

finally in your `viewController`

```
  MyData *myData=[MyData getInstance];
  [myData search];
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all controllers in an `NSArray *`, lets say it is called `controllerArray`.

Then you can make all controllers perform selector with:

```
[controllerArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(doSearch)];
```

Comment: I am afraid that, this will require all the controllers to be initialized first. Otherwise, it will be invoked on `nil` object, which will provide no result.

Comment: Ofcourse they will have to be initialized. That doesn't mean their views have to be loaded.

Comment: Got different point of view; I really don't like to initialize all the VCs in `applicationDidFinishedLaunchingWithOptions`; personal opinion, nothing else.

Comment: No need to do that at the very app start. Whenever you initialize a certain VC you add it to controllersArray (make it NSMutableArray). In either way: before you want to call doSearch selector of a certain VC you will have to initialize it.

Comment: There are usually many ways to solve a certain problem. Not always one is better than the other :)

Answer (score 0):

Add your method to `AppDelegate.m` file

```
- (void)doSearch
{
   NSLog(@"Search..!");
}
```

And Add `#import "AppDelegate.h"` In `UIViewController` that you want to call :

You can call method by,

```
AppDelegate *del = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[del performSelector:@selector(doSearch) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

From Any `UIViewController`

Comment: How come without declaring the method in `AppDelegate.h` it will be accessible to other classes ??

Comment: I meant to say that you need to declare `- (void)doSearch;` in `AppDelegate.h` in order to make that method visible to Any ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You may like to read below tutorial

[Global functions and variables in Objective C](http://sree.cc/iphone/global-functions-and-variables-in-objective-c)

or You can create methods in the appDelegate class that you can access through all your app. For example, in your **AppDelegate.h** you have declared this method as follow:

```
-(void)myMethod;
```

In your **AppDelegate.m**, you define it as:

```
-(void)myMethod
{
    NSLog(@"myMethod is getting called");
}
```

From any other classes (Master or Detail, etc.), you access myMethod by:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate myMethod];
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to make a separate header file make this method a class method and you can call this anywhere in the project by importing the class.And you can include this class into your pch file so that import can be avoided from all VCs

```
class.h

+ (void)doSearch
{
   NSLog(@"Search..!");
}
```

in ViewControllers

```
#import "class.h"

    
-(void)someMethod
{
    [class doSearch];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make `AbstractViewController` and inside it add all your common behaviors or methods. Any `ViewController` will inherits from the Abstract and can call any common Method